# Pandas, Python: rotate some (31-day) columns of a dataframe and match them to the existing (year, month) rows (NOAA data)

Tags: python, pandas

I have NOAA weather data.  In it raw state it has year and month as rows and then days as columns. I want to expand the number of rows so that each row has a year, month, and day with the appropriate data in each row.

There is also a weather variables column where each row represents a different weather variable collected each month.  The number of weather variables collected in a month can change.  (In January there are two (tmax, tmin), in February there are three (tmax, tmin, prcp), and in March there is one (tmin).)

Here is an example df.

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'station': ['USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1'],
           'year': [1993, 1993, 1993, 1993,1993, 1993],
           'month': [1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 3],
           'attribute':['tmax', 'tmin', 'tmax', 'tmin', 'prcp', 'tmax'],
           'day1': range(1, 7, 1),
           'day2': range(1, 7, 1),
           'day3': range(1, 7, 1),
           'day4': range(1, 7, 1),
                  })
example_df = example_df[['station', 'year', 'month', 'attribute', 'day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4']]
```

This is the solution I want,

```
solution_df = pd.DataFrame({'station': ['USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1','USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1', 'USC1'],
           'year': [1993, 1993, 1993, 1993,1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993,1993, 1993],
           'month': [1, 1,1, 1, 2, 2,  2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
           'day':[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           'tmax': [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6],
           'tmin': [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
           'prcp': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 5, 5, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]

                  })
solution_df = solution_df[['station', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'tmax', 'tmin', 'prcp']]
```

I have tried .T, pivot, melt, stack, and unstack to get the day columns to be rows with the correct months.

This is as close as I have gotten to success with the example dataset.

```
record_arr = example_df.to_records()

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'station': np.nan,
                  'year': np.nan,
                  'month':np.nan, 
                  'day': np.nan,
                  'tmax':np.nan,
                  'tmin': np.nan,
                  'prcp':np.nan},
                   index = [1]
                 )
new_df.append ({'station': record_arr[0][1], 'year': record_arr[0][2], 'month':record_arr[0][3], 'tmax':record_arr[0][5], 'tmin':record_arr[1][5] }, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires pivot as well as melt (or unstack and stack). This is how I got it in two steps

```
df1 = example_df.set_index(['station', 'year', 'month', 'attribute']).stack().reset_index()
df1.set_index(['station', 'year', 'month', 'level_4','attribute'])[0].unstack().reset_index()


attribute   station year    month   level_4 prcp    tmax    tmin
0           USC1    1993    1       day1    NaN     1.0     2.0
1           USC1    1993    1       day2    NaN     1.0     2.0
2           USC1    1993    1       day3    NaN     1.0     2.0
3           USC1    1993    1       day4    NaN     1.0     2.0
4           USC1    1993    2       day1    5.0     3.0     4.0
5           USC1    1993    2       day2    5.0     3.0     4.0
6           USC1    1993    2       day3    5.0     3.0     4.0
7           USC1    1993    2       day4    5.0     3.0     4.0
8           USC1    1993    3       day1    NaN     6.0     NaN
9           USC1    1993    3       day2    NaN     6.0     NaN
10          USC1    1993    3       day3    NaN     6.0     NaN
11          USC1    1993    3       day4    NaN     6.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked perfectly with the actual data (GHCN-DAILY station data from NOAA).